# How to delete *.bak files recursively older than a specific date depending on directory in file path?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file for Windows 7.

I currently have a code that deletes old backups from our masters folders within our site management folders. This is the code:

```
for /d %%A in ("Y:\*.*") do del /s /q /f "%%A\masters\*.bak"
```

However I need to code it to only delete things that are older than 3 years, which would be this code:

```
forfiles /P "Y:\" /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "cmd /C del @path"
```

However I need what is in the top code so that I can delete all *.bak files from the `masters` folders that exist within our 173 site management folders. I'm ripping my hair out figuring this out. I can't have it deleting *.bak files from our other folders.

I've tried combining the code, but below command line in batch file does not work as expected:

```
forfiles /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "cmd /C for /d %%A in ("Y:\*.*") do del /s /q /f "%%A\masters\*.bak"
```

How to delete all *.bak files older than 3 years anywhere in directory tree if second directory in file path is `masters` and keep all other *.bak files being newer or in a directory where second directory in file path is not `masters`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create first a batch file `C:\Temp\DeleteBackup.bat` with the following commands:

```
@echo off
set "BackupFileName=%~1"
if not "%BackupFileName:\masters\=%" == "%BackupFileName%" ECHO del "%BackupFileName%"
```

This batch code checks if the file name with full path and file extension contains anywhere `\masters\` by removing this string case-insensitive from left argument of string comparison.

If the remaining string is not equal the unmodified file name string because of containing `\masters\` in path, the **IF** condition is true and the backup file would be deleted if there would not be command **ECHO** which results in just displaying the **DEL** command line.

For example the complete list of backup files is:

```
Y:\masters\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Test1.bak
Y:\Folder2\masters\Level3\Test2.bak
Y:\Folder3\Level2\masters\Level4\Test3.bak
Y:\Folder4\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Test4.bak
Y:\Folder5\Level2\Test5.bak
Y:\Folder6\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Level6\Test6.bak
Y:\Folder7\masters\Test7.bak
```

The files deleted would be:

```
Y:\masters\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Test1.bak
Y:\Folder2\masters\Level3\Test2.bak
Y:\Folder3\Level2\masters\Level4\Test3.bak
Y:\Folder7\masters\Test7.bak
```

And the files remaining would be:

```
Y:\Folder4\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Test4.bak
Y:\Folder5\Level2\Test5.bak
Y:\Folder6\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Level6\Test6.bak
```

Then use in your batch file:

```
forfiles /P "Y:\" /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "C:\Temp\DeleteBackup.bat @PATH"
```

It is of course possible to modify `DeleteBackup.bat` to check if directory in second directory hierarchy level is `masters`.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=3 delims=\" %%I in ("%~1") do if /I "%%I" == "masters" ECHO del "%~1"
```

This code would delete from the complete list above the files:

```
Y:\Folder2\masters\Level3\Test2.bak
Y:\Folder7\masters\Test7.bak
```

And the files remaining would be:

```
Y:\masters\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Test1.bak
Y:\Folder3\Level2\masters\Level4\Test3.bak
Y:\Folder4\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Test4.bak
Y:\Folder5\Level2\Test5.bak
Y:\Folder6\Level2\Level3\Level4\Level5\Level6\Test6.bak
```

---

[Robert Chizmadia Jr.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8377004/robert-chizmadia-jr) asked in an already deleted comment:

**Is it possible to use GOTO instead of calling another batch file on FORFILES command line?**

The answer on this additional question:

**FORFILES** is not an internal command of `cmd.exe` like **FOR**. It is a console application stored in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` if used version of Windows has it pre-installed at all.

The command to execute as specified after **FORFILES** option `/C` must be an executable or script. That is the reason why `cmd /C` is always used when an internal command of Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` like **DEL** should be executed by **FORFILES** whereby the really complete command would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C`.

So it is not possible to use a command like **GOTO** in **FORFILES** command as there is no executable or script with name **GOTO**.

Also **GOTO** in a **FOR** loop exits the loop and therefore interpreting of command lines of batch files continues on another position in batch file.

However, it is possible to use the same batch file for the file path evaluation and backup file deletion as used to run **FORFILES** command.

Example 1 with batch file not expecting any parameter for default operation:

```
@echo off
if not "%~1" == "" (
    for /F "tokens=3 delims=\" %%I in ("%~1") do if /I "%%I" == "masters" ECHO del "%~1"
    goto :EOF
)

%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "Y:\" /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "%~f0 @PATH"
```

If this batch file is executed with an argument, it runs the **FOR** loop written to check if second directory in file path is `masters` and delete this file in this case after removing **ECHO**. Otherwise on starting the batch file without any parameter the batch file runs the **FORFILES** executable.

Example 2 with batch file expecting 1 or more parameters for default operation:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "#Delete:Backup#" (
    for /F "tokens=3 delims=\" %%I in ("%~2") do if /I "%%I" == "masters" ECHO del "%~2"
    goto :EOF
)

rem Other commands processing the parameters.

%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "Y:\" /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "%~f0 #Delete:Backup# @PATH"

rem More commands executed after the deletion of the backup files.
```

This is nearly the same as example 1 with the difference that if first parameter used on running the batch file is case-sensitive the string `#Delete:Backup#`, the batch file expects as second parameter the name of a backup file with full path being deleted if second directory in file path is `masters`.

Like in all batch code examples the command **ECHO** must be removed before `del` command also in this code example to really execute the deletion of the backup files.

---

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `forfiles /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`