# Writing a Batch file that deletes 3 year old files within specific subdirectories of subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file for Windows 7.

I currently have a code that deletes old backups from our masters folders within our site management folders. This is the code:

```
for /d %%A in ("Y:\*.*") do del /s /q /f "%%A\masters\*.bak"
```

However I need to code it to only delete things that are older than 3 years, which would be this code:

```
forfiles /P "Y:\" /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "cmd /C del @path"
```

However I need what is in the top code so that I can delete all *.bak files from the `masters` folders that exist within our 173 site management folders. I'm ripping my hair out figuring this out. I can't have it deleting *.bak files from our other folders.

I've tried combining the code, but below command line in batch file does not work as expected:

```
forfiles /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "cmd /C for /d %%A in ("Y:\*.*") do del /s /q /f "%%A\masters\*.bak"
```

How to delete all *.bak files older than 3 years anywhere in directory tree if second directory in file path is `masters` and keep all other *.bak files being newer or in a directory where second directory in file path is not `masters`?

imgur.com/a/isTOm here is the directory. I cant make a dump due to my permissions on the drive so this is the best I can do.

how do I make it so it deletes from the:
| America - US | Canada | GME | GMIO | GMSA | Mexico |
Folders only as well as the WIP and MASTERS folders within the site folders in each of those 6 directories that are 3 years old or older?

Thanks in advance!!

@Mofi tried to help me here but after at work they changed folders around, MOFI advised me to make a new question rather than editing his own, [How to delete *.bak files recursively older than a specific date depending on directory in file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354418/how-to-delete-bak-files-recursively-older-than-a-specific-date-depending-on-di/45357032#45357032) here you go.

Comment: What is "not working as expected" for the third command? (i.e., what is it doing vs. what you expect to do?)

Comment: i want to have it so it deletes .bak files older than 3 years using the FORFILES command as well as being able to go like this Y:\GME\~RandomSiteName~\Wip and delete all the files there and do that for every site folder within these 6 regional folders. as well as doing the same thing for the Masters folders that exist within the site folders.

I basically tried to mix the code together but I cant get it to work to both use that folder wildcard as well as the 3 years requirement.

Comment: like I cannot have it deleting things from our bim360 folder, FM folder, or any folder other than the WIP and MASTER folders that exist in the site directories that exist within the regional folders on our Y drive.

Comment: basically I get a syntax error. apparently to do this properly I need to make an IF statement, but theres not a lot listeded about making IF statements such as %~1% or setting token values... ive tried looking it up but im at that point ehere im pulling my hair out @JeffZeitlin

Comment: You should reproduce the exact text of the error message, especially if it indicates the context in which the error occurs. Also, if you're working on Windows 7 or later, you might want to consider doing this in Powershell instead.

Comment: @Mofi you told me to make a whole new question due to the prerequisites changing. don't call me out for something you told me to do. you were very vague with the help. you told me to delete my comments. no I didn't get it working because I didn't understand the IF statement. you didn't explain what token meant or the %~1% statements. I already presented everything here to you and you said I should ask a new question because this has an entirely new prerequisite. I would have been able to test it on a test directory if you explained it a bit more, but you deferred me to make a new question...

Comment: @Mofi I added the prior post. but I don't understand why I had to make a new question here rather than you altering your answer before hand. I don't see how there can be confusion here. its basically the same thing but they altered the file structure. I showed you the new structure. its the same thing nearly.

Comment: i said before in a comment that i deleted that i cant get you a directory because of permissions. running CMD as administrator still says access denied

Comment: I gave you an example of the directory in that imgur link. why would we need a whole directory for a utility we are going to use every 4 months? you think hard coding each path would be a good idea?

Comment: Alright, but its well over 5000 characters. because of how slow the VPN is, it took me 3 hours just to get this. this isn't it the entire directory. I can get the ENTIRE Directory maybe on Monday (my laptop keeps exiting the VPN because it keeps idling, so ill get the FULL LIST if you need that @Mofi ) https://www.mediafire.com/file/bba5784cyb9conz/Document.txt

Comment: All those are directories. Yes, if 3 years old, all get deleted. Yup third directory level for both the wip and masters

Answer (score 0):

I used `Document.txt` and the following batch code for testing the code at top of the batch file:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "#Delete:Backup#" (
    for /F "tokens=4 delims=\" %%I in ("%~2") do (
        if /I "%%I" == "masters" (
            ECHO del from line %Line%: "%~2"
        ) else if /I "%%I" == "wip" (
            ECHO del from line %Line%: "%~2"
        )
    )
    goto :EOF
)

set "Line=1"
for /F "delims=" %%# in (Document.txt) do (
    call "%~f0" #Delete:Backup# "%%#"
    set /A Line+=1
)
```

The output was for the 1219 lines in `Document.txt`:

```
del from line 19: "Y:\America - US\Milford\WIP\Site\29678-EDM\156400000-CS1-00.bak"
del from line 20: "Y:\America - US\Milford\WIP\1908\20170721_05.59\156401908-IF1-L1.bak"
del from line 21: "Y:\America - US\Milford\WIP\1908\20170721_05.59\156401908-AE1-L1.bak"
del from line 22: "Y:\America - US\Milford\WIP\1908\20170721_05.59\30083-EDM\156401908-1500086IF1-L1.bak"
del from line 34: "Y:\America - US\Milford\Masters\1908\156401908-AE1-L1.bak"
del from line 48: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\20005\20170804_09.09\156320005-IF1-01.bak"
del from line 49: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\20005\20170804_09.09\156320005-IF1-L1.bak"
del from line 50: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\20005\20170804_09.09\156320005-IF1-02.bak"
del from line 51: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\20005\20170804_09.09\156320005-IF1-03.bak"
del from line 52: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\20005\20170804_09.09\AEB cabinet modifications Duane\156320005-IF1-02_SOM.bak"
del from line 53: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\20005\20170804_09.09\AEB cabinet modifications Duane\156320005-IF1-L1_SOM.bak"
del from line 54: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\20005\20170804_09.09\AEB cabinet modifications Duane\156320005-IF1-01_SOM.bak"
del from line 55: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\20005\20170804_09.09\AEB cabinet modifications Duane\156320005-IF1-03_SOM.bak"
del from line 56: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\1971\30147-EDM\156301971-EL1-03.bak"
del from line 57: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\1971\30147-EDM\156301971-EL1-02.bak"
del from line 58: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\1971\30138-EDM\156301971-AC1-L1.bak"
del from line 59: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\1971\30138-EDM\156301971-EL1-L1.bak"
del from line 60: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\WIP\1971\30138-EDM\156301971-AE1-L1.bak"
del from line 139: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\4606\156304606-IF1-L1g.bak"
del from line 140: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\4606\156304606-IF1-L1f.bak"
del from line 141: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\4606\156304606-IF1-L1.bak"
del from line 142: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\9227\156309227-IF1-01.bak"
del from line 143: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\20005\156320005-IF1-L1.bak"
del from line 144: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1971\156301971-IF1-L1w.bak"
del from line 145: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1971\156301971-IF1-L1e.bak"
del from line 146: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1971\156301971-IF1-L1.bak"
del from line 147: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1971\156301971-AC1-L1.bak"
del from line 148: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1971\156301971-EL1-L1.bak"
del from line 149: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1971\156301971-AE1-L1.bak"
del from line 150: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1958\156301958-IF1-02.bak"
del from line 151: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\19867\156319867-IF1-09.bak"
del from line 152: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\19867\156319867-IF1-02.bak"
del from line 153: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\19867\156319867-IF1-06.bak"
del from line 154: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\19867\156319867-IF1-07.bak"
del from line 155: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1963\156301963-IF1-02.bak"
del from line 156: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1979\156301979-AE1-01.bak"
del from line 157: "Y:\America - US\Warren Tech Center\Masters\1979\156301979-IF1-01.bak"
```

That looks right and therefore the code to use is:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "#Delete:Backup#" (
    for /F "tokens=4 delims=\" %%I in ("%~2") do (
        if /I "%%I" == "masters" (
            del "%~2"
        ) else if /I "%%I" == "wip" (
            del "%~2"
        )
    )
    goto :EOF
)

rem Other commands processing the parameters.

%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "Y:\" /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "%~f0 #Delete:Backup# @PATH"

rem More commands executed after the deletion of the backup files.
```

Then I though you might add additional directories in future and therefore a better code structure than this would be helpful for you to add additional directories. So I thought a little and tested following modified version again first using `Documen.txt` with the 1219 *.bak file names with full path.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "#Delete:Backup#" (
    for /F "tokens=4 delims=\" %%I in ("%~2") do (
        for %%J in (masters wip) do if /I "%%I" == "%%~J" ECHO del from line %Line%: "%~2" & goto :EOF
    )
    goto :EOF
)

set "Line=1"
for /F "delims=" %%# in (Document.txt) do (
    call "%~f0" #Delete:Backup# "%%#"
    set /A Line+=1
)
```

This code produced exactly the same output as first code. So you could also use:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "#Delete:Backup#" (
    for /F "tokens=4 delims=\" %%I in ("%~2") do (
        for %%J in (masters wip) do if /I "%%I" == "%%~J" del "%~2" & goto :EOF
    )
    goto :EOF
)

rem Other commands processing the parameters.

%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "Y:\" /S /D -1096 /M *.bak /C "%~f0 #Delete:Backup# @PATH"

rem More commands executed after the deletion of the backup files.
```

Additional directories on **third** directory level can be easily added on line with `masters wip`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the task: delete all old files from folders that have path `*\*\Masters`.

1. Get full paths of all folders with `dir /S /B` This will output full
   paths of all folders in the current path recursively.
2. Filter the folders with command `findstr /R /C:"Y:\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*\\masters$"`. It will output only the paths that
   match the reqexp. Note the doubled slashes.
   `[^\\]*\\[^\\]*\\masters$` matches lines that have exactly three
   hierarchy parts and end with `masters`. For use in batch `^` symbol
   must be doubled as it is special escape symbol.
3. Execute `forfiles` over found path

Schematically it would look like

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir masters /S /B ^| findstr /R /C:"Y:\\[^^\\]*\\[^^\\]*\\masters$"') do (
  :: %%f contains full path to "masters" folder
  forfiles ... 
)
```